# Symfony2 Doctrine handling polish characters

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I did everything i could to get polish characters in my symfony2 project, but i failed. I persist my object to database from Request like that:

```
$mail = new Mail();
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($mail)
        ->add('to_id', 'integer', array('label' => 'Adresat (ID):'))
        ->add('subject', 'text', array('label' => 'Temat:', 'max_length' => 255, 'attr' => array('class' => 'mail')))
        ->add('data', 'textarea', array('label' => 'Treść:', 'attr' => array('class' => 'mail')))
        ->getForm();
if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
  $form->bindRequest($request);
  $em->persist($mail);
  $em->flush();
}
```

Unfortunately, in database, polish characters are represented by question marks. Same thing when i get it back to view. Every settings looks good, config.yml:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        charset:  UTF8
```

and

```
framework:
    charset:         UTF-8
```

Schema in database got charset utf8 and collation utf8_polish_ci

Anyone got this problem too?

I'm using NetBeans 7.2 with Encoding set to UTF-8 in project options

@EDIT: I dropped whole schema, recreated it and it works fine. So i didnt find solution, but i suppose that creating schema in MySQL Workbench did something bad with encoding (did it manually with CREATE SCHEMA).

Comment: There is a very good document that talks about encodings and all the different things that can make a web page not work with international character sets (there are many!). I recommend you read it carefully and try to find out what is wrong in your case: http://htmlpurifier.org/docs/enduser-utf8.html

Comment: When you find out, don't forget to post the solution!

Comment: I read it and found nothing. Everything seems to be properly set

Comment: Maybe you can try to at least find out where the problem originates: when you receive the data in the controller, is it OK or does it have the question marks? If it is Ok, are the SQL queries OK ( you can check them with the profiler)?

Comment: I found solution, seems like MySQL Workbench created schema with bad encoding. Creating it manually worked just fine. Thx for help!